# angular , find data from the client using id (Angular Observable)

Tags: angular, typescript, feathersjs

I want to call the api endpoint from the database from the client side and I am using observable.

The current code calls http://localhost:3030/humans/id?343 instead of http://localhost:3030/humans/343

what seem to be the issue on my query ? query: { id: 343 } ?

## here I want to find human based on the id

```
findHuman(formGroup: FormGroup): Observable<Human[]> {
  return from(this.feathers.service('human').find<Human>({
    query: { id: 343 }
    }))
    .pipe(
      map((result) => result.data)
    );
}
```

Comment: end your call with *humans?id=343*

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: The above code calls `http://localhost:3030/humans/humans?id=343`. Is your intention to call `http://localhost:3030/humans/343`?

Comment: The call to the endpoint may need to be `http://localhost:3030/humans?id=343`

Comment: @tenkmilan , yes , based on the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the [`get` service method](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html#get-id-params) is used for:

```
findHuman(formGroup: FormGroup): Observable<Human[]> {
  return from(this.feathers.service('human').get<Human>(343)
    .pipe(
      map((result) => result.data)
    );
}
```

For more information on how service methods map to URLs also see the [REST client HTTP API](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client/rest.html#http-api).

Comment: how about for Find ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61311924/how-to-use-subscribe-and-use-the-angular-find-service-method

Answer (score 0):

If the `http://localhost:3030/humans` url is called with `id=343` query you get `http://localhost:3030/humans/humans?id=343`. The query is part of the url. [For derails see this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

If you want to have the id as url parameter, which means to call `http://localhost:3030/humans/343` than the `343` parameter has to be put directly in the url on client side.