# How to use subscribe and use the angular find service method?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I wanted to get the result which maches the query. I've tested the api so basically the api has no problem , the problem is with my angular code.

I wanted to return the data the maches the "where" query , and then I use subcribe but it returns empty , any idea? . Thank you.

## Angular service

```
checkExistingFeedbackRequest(formGroup: FormGroup): Observable<FeedbackRequest[]> {
  return from(this.service.find<FeedbackRequest>({
    where: {
      formId: formGroup.Id,
      respondentId: formGroup.respondentId,
      recipientId:formGroup.recipientId,
      periodStartDate: formGroup.periodStartDate,
      periodEndDate: formGroup.periodEndDate),
    },
  }))
    .pipe(
      map((result) => result.data)
    );
}
```

## component.ts

```
 let test = this.requestFormService.checkExistingFeedbackRequest(this.form)
      .subscribe((result) => {
        console.log("result", result)
      })
```

Comment: what returns this service 'this.service.find ()'

Comment: Press F12 click on network tab. You'll see the outbound request. Does it look right?